# Error al convertir int(*)[columnas] to int(*)[12] para argumento de método

Tags: c++

Estoy haciendo un juego en C++ y, al pasar la matriz como parámetro de la función Juego(), me salta el error.

```
Error C++: Cannot convert int (*) [columnas] to int (*) [12] for argument 4 to void Juego (Laberinto<int>, int, int, int(*) [12]
```

El error está en la línea donde llamo a la función `Juego()` en el main, justo donde paso la variable matriz. No sé donde está el error, pero de seguro es algo fácil de lo que no me puedo dar cuenta. Sea como sea, no me deja avanzar con el juego para poder terminarlo. Si alguien sabe como solucionarlo, desde ya muchas gracias por su ayuda.

**main.cpp**

```
       #include <iostream>
       #include "Laberinto.h"

       using namespace std;



       const int maxPuntos = 5;
       const int posInicial = 0;
       void ComoJugar();
       void Juego(Laberinto<int> LAB, int, int, int [][12]);

      int main()
      {
         Laberinto<int> LAB;
         int filas = 12;
         int columnas = 12;
         int matriz[filas][columnas];
         ComoJugar();
         Juego(LAB, filas, columnas, matriz);
         return 0;
      }

      void ComoJugar()
      {
         cout << "********** LABERINTO **********" << endl;
         cout << endl;
         cout << "Bienvenido al juego del laberinto. A continuacion se detallaran las instrucciones." << endl;
         cout << endl;
         cout << "1) El juego consiste en un laberinto de tamano nxn el que los juagdores solo pueden moverse de forma horizontal y vertical." << endl;
         cout << "2) Durante el recorrido, los jugadores recogeran un maximo de 5 puntos." << endl;
         cout << "3) Gana el primer jugador que salga del tablero. Si hay empate, gana el que mas puntos haya recogido durante el juego." << endl;
         cout << endl;
         cout << "Presiona la tecla [Enter] para continuar." << endl;
        //Leer tecla;
        //Borrar pantalla;
    }

    void Juego(Laberinto<int> LAB, int filas, int columnas, int matriz[][12])
    {
        LAB.MostrarLaberinto();
        int pos = 0;
        bool esMuro = false;
        bool GANASTE = false;
        bool Perdiste = true;
        int puntos = 0;

       for(int i = 0; i < filas; i++)
       {
         for(int j = 0; j < columnas; j++)
         {
             cout << matriz[i][j] << endl;
         }
       }

       if(puntos == 0)
       {
          Perdiste = true;
          cout << "Perdiste :(" << endl;
       }

       if(puntos >= maxPuntos && pos == 12)
       {
          GANASTE = true;
          cout << "Has encontrado la salida!!! GANASTE!!!" << endl;
       }
  }
```

Comment: Declara la `matriz[12][12]` en lugar de usar variables para sus dimensiones. Si quieres también puedes usar constantes como `#DEFINE FILAS 12`, y usarlas como dimensiones de la matriz.

Comment: Seguro que te da error en la llamada a la función Juego?? Hay un error previo en la definición de matriz, como te han dicho en comentarios anteriores. No puedes usar variables para definir las dimensiones de un array constante.

Answer (score 1):

Necesitas que las filas y las columnas de tu matriz sean constantes:

```
     const int filas = 12;
     const int columnas = 12;
//   ^^^^^ <--- Constante
     int matriz[filas][columnas];
```

Esto le dice al compilador que esos valores no van a cambiar durante la ejecución y por tanto estarán disponibles e invariables en tiempo de compilación, condición necesaria para saber el tamaño del dato que está siendo pasado como parámetro, si te fijas el error ya te da una pista de que desconoce el tamaño:

> ```
> Error C++: Cannot convert int (*) [columnas] to int (*) [12]
> ```

Error: no puedo convertir `int (*) [columnas]` a `int (*) [12]`. No sabe cuál es el valor de `columnas` porque es una variable, al transformarlo en constante el problema desaparece.

---

Otra cosa a tener en cuenta es que puedes pasar la matriz por referencia, conservando ambos tamaños:

```
void Juego(Laberinto<int> LAB, int, int, int (&)[12][12]);

// ...

void Juego(Laberinto<int> LAB, int filas, int columnas, int (&matriz)[12][12])
```

Esto te proporciona seguridad de tipos (no podrás pasar ninguna matriz que no sea de 12x12) y al conservar los tamaños te permite usar el `for` de rango:

```
for (const auto &fila : matriz)
{
  for (const auto &valor : fila)
  {
      cout << valor << endl;
  }
}
```